# How to get distinct values of a column in rquery?

Tags: r, rquery

Exploring the `rquery` package of John Mount, Win-Vector LLC, is there a way that I could get the distinct values of a column from a SQL table using the `rquery` package functions?  (WITHOUT writing the appropriate SQL query but using the `rquery` functions since I need to use my code in Oracle, MSSQL and Postgres).
So I do not need:

```
rq_get_query(db, "SELECT DISTINCT (COL1) FROM TABLE1")
```

but I am looking for something similar to *unique* of base R.

Comment: Didn't hear about `rquery` package until today. However, there is [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/sqldf.pdf) package as well which might help you.

Comment: What happens when you try `rq_get_query(db, "SELECT DISTINCT COL1 FROM TABLE1")`?  It looks like that command should work from the rquery package.  If you are interested in querying a SQL table, I generally use the `RODBC` package.

Comment: @RonakShah : How can you use `sqldf` in an RDBMS environment like Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres?

Comment: @KerryJackson It is true that your answer will work but as I mentioned initially I want to avoid writing SQL since I want my code to work directly to Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres without changing queries syntax and this is what `rquery` is introducing. Moreover, I have been using RODBC for a few years but it seems that ROracle and RPostgreSQL are up to 10 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `sqldf` package. It is very accessible, and think you would benefit.

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
df = sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT COL1 FROM TABLE1")
View(df)
```

Comment: sqldf works well to query a R dataframe using SQL, and can also be used to query a csv file, but I don't think it is easy to use it to query a SQL table (by which I think VassilisGeorgiou is referring to a table in a SQL Server database)

Comment: Wasn't sure if OP meant datafeame by SQL table or if he/she is connected to a database, but I agree!

Answer (score 0):

This returns the distinct values of `Col1` and `Col2`. Can of course be any number of columns.

```
db_td(connection, "table") %.>%
   project(., groupby = c("Col1", "Col2"), one = 0) %.>%
   execute(connection, .)
```

The assignment of `0` to a new column is necessary, is supposed to be fixed in the next update of `rquery`, so it will work like this:

`project(., groupby = c("Col1", "Col2"))`